# How can i call DTO in domain layer if it must be implemented on application layer?

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design, dto

I'm developing a project with .NET and I'm trying to implement DDD design with onion architecture. I read some articles and my understanding was: the application layer must contain the DTOs and the domain layer must contain the services (only the ones responsible for
business rules).
That said, let's get to the problem: In my domain services, I can't import my DTOs because it's in the application layer and my domain layer can't import anything from there.
How can I resolve this? Did I build it wrong or in the wrong order?
Code I'm trying to write:

```
Task SetCategories(List<SetCategoriesRequest> categories);
```

The error:

> The type or namespace name 'type/namespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use your app-layer DTOs as domain models.  Generally the domain would contain *models* of the objects/entities used in the domain.  Things like a "category", as known to the domain, would be modeled within the domain layer.  Layers which reference the domain can use its models, and can optionally convert the data from those models into DTOs *if needed*.

Comment: I'm actually trying to use these dtos in the body of domain services methods. I also have the domain models

Answer (score 1):

> the domain layer must contain the services

**And** the models used by those services.  For example, in the code shown there is a semantic concept of a "category".  If this entity is part of the business domain then that domain would contain a class which models this entity.  Any domain-specific, technology-agnostic attributes and aspects of that semantic concept would be included in that domain model.

The application layer and infrastructure layer(s) can reference the domain and use its models, but the domain should not reference the other layers.

So for example in a web application you might have controller actions which invoke business operations related to a "category".  Those controller actions can directly use that model where it makes sense to do so.

In the event that any given layer needs to re-shape the data for purposes specific to that layer (view models for specific UI interactions, DTOs for interacting with external web services, etc.) those layers can also define their own DTOs for that purpose.  Any conversion between the domain models and the layer-specific DTOs would happen in that layer.

When interacting with the domain, that interaction would use domain models.  So in this case if `SetCategories` is a domain operation which is performed on a collection of "categories" then it would expect a collection of `Category` *domain models* (or perhaps some aggregate domain model which contains a collection of `Category` domain models), not an application layer DTO.

Comment: Yes, i have the "category" as a domain model in my domain layer, and it works fine. Perhaps in this example that I give, my question has not been explained in the best possible way. For example I have another method in domain service and this method is responsible for returning a dto with some data. How can i return this dto if my domain layer can't see the dto?

Comment: @guirms: The point of separating the core domain layer from application and infrastructure layers is to *separate* them.  So I guess to answer what you've asked... You *don't* return that DTO if that DTO is not part of the core domain.  Whether that DTO *should be* part of the core domain or whether the domain operation should return something else instead is entirely up to you, this community doesn't know enough about your domain to decide that.  But to the question of "how can the domain use app-layer objects" the answer is "it shouldn't".

Comment: In my conception, this dto should be a part of the domain layer, but i read some articles that said that "dtos must be in application layer". But now, after your explanation, I think it can be built in the domain layer if it's up to you, right?

Comment: @guirms: I can't speak to whether or not that would be the best approach in your case because I know nothing of your domain.  I can say that in my experience it's *very rare* for the domain to include anything I might conceptually call a DTO.  Though it's not uncommon to contain aggregate models which represent a domain operation.  For example, a "create category request" may be an object which contains information about a `Category` (but not a `Category` itself, since it hasn't been created yet).  One might call this a DTO, subjectively.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thanks, David!